# What does "co supp" mean?

Tags: notation

For $S\subset \mathbb{R}^l$, let $\psi:\mathbb{R}^l\to M(S,\mathbb{B}_{S})$, where $M(S,\mathbb{B}_{S})$ is the set of probability measures on $S$ with its Borel $\sigma$-field. For $p\in S$, what does int co supp $\psi(p)\ne \emptyset$ mean? It may be worth noting that $S$ is a manifold (but I have no familiarity with manifolds, so it may very well not be).

int is given explicitly as interior, supp is most likely support. Just not sure what the whole thing is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: co sometimes refers to the complement. e.g. something is co-finite if its complement is finite, co-meagre if its complement is meagre. So it could be that the interior of the complement of the support of $\psi(p)$ is non-empty. I don't know anything about this field though so it's just a guess.

Comment: I think this interpretation makes good sense in the context. Thanks a bunch for the quick response!